# List of Map to case Class scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a router related data which is in following format:-

```
List(Map(routerId -> testR1, 
        config -> 
        List(
            Map(pin -> X12, color -> YELLOW), 
            Map(pin -> M20, color -> BLACK)
            )
        ),
    Map(routerId -> testR3,
        config -> 
        List(
            Map(pin -> M12, color -> YELLOW), 
            Map(pin -> X20, color -> BLACK),
            Map(pin -> M11, color -> RED)
            )
        )   

    )
```

and I have a Router case class

```
case class Router(routerId: String, modelInfo: List[Map[String,String]])
```

I am trying to create a list of Router for which I tried cast using asInstanceOf somewhat like this:

```
val data =  request.get("data").get.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, List[Map[String, String]]]]]
```

But, I would prefer not to cast it if possible. Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: 
The request is actually the json request which looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
            {
                "routerId": "testR1",
                "config": [
                    {
                        "pin": "X12",
                        "color": "Red"
                    },
                    {
                        "pin": "M15",
                        "color": "Yellow"
                    },
                    {
                        "pin": "X20",
                        "color": "Yellow"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "routerId": "testR2",
                "config": [
                    {
                        "pin": "X20",
                        "color": "Black"
                    },
                    {
                        "pin": "M11",
                        "color": "Yellow"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am using play 2 which is actually converting it to the List[Map...] format.

P.S. - I am a newbie to scala.

Comment: It is a little unclear on what you are trying to do. You have some List and router case class, however the "val data = request..." portion is unclear to me. What is request? what are you trying to do?

Comment: @AssafMendelson, Sorry about that just added some more content. Please see the edit.

Comment: What does request.get("data") return?

Comment: @Tanjin it returns : Some(List(Map(routerId -> testR1, 
  config -> 
  List(
   Map(pin -> X12, color -> YELLOW), 
   Map(pin -> M20, color -> BLACK)
   )
  ), 
 Map(routerId -> testR2,
  config -> 
  List(
   Map(pin -> X20, color -> RED), 
   Map(pin -> M22, color -> BLACK)
   )
  ),
 Map(routerId -> testR3,
  config -> 
  List(
   Map(pin -> M12, color -> YELLOW), 
   Map(pin -> X20, color -> BLACK),
   Map(pin -> M11, color -> RED)
   )
  ) 
  
 ))

Comment: what is the output you want for that input?

Comment: @mrsrinivas, I would like to create a list of Device class for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use play-json like this ..

```
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val reads = Json.reads[Router]

val jsResult: JsResult[Router] = Json.fromJson[Router](jsonString)

println(jsResult.get)
```

for more see

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonAutomated

Comment: Actually, you need `implicit val reads = Json.reads[Router]`, not `List[Router]` (which will throw a compilation error).

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet changed  List[Router] to Router.
`import play.api.libs.json._
 implicit val reads = play.api.libs.json.Json.reads[Router]
    val jsonString: JsValue = play.api.libs.json.Json.parse(HTTPRespJsonEntityConvetor.convert(request))

    val jsResult: JsResult[Router] = play.api.libs.json.Json.fromJson[Router](jsonString)

    println(jsResult.get)`
But giving compilation error: Error:No implicit Reads for akka.routing.RoutingLogic, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[akka.routing.Routee] available.
    implicit val reads = play.api.libs.json.Json.reads[Router]

Comment: Check that you haven't imported `akka.routing.Router` by mistake, instead of your own `Router`.

Comment: Thanks @CyrilleCorpet, changed.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet, Sorry but I don't have a Router class defined. My routes are places in <Project_Home>/conf/routes file. Do I need to create one?

Comment: You said in your question that you had a case class `Router`; I assumed it was yours. Here, it seems you are calling `Json.reads` on a case class which has different fields from the one you described. You should try to find which `Router` class is in the scope when you're calling `Json.reads`.

Comment: Ah... Thanks for pointing that out. Silly me. Finally it looks clean now. Thanks a lot @CyrilleCorpet  you saved my day :)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Accepting the answer